# ArgumentResolvers within single transaction?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, transactions

I am wondering if there is a way to wrap all argument resolvers like for `@PathVariables` or `@ModelAttributes` into one *single* transaction? We are already using the OEMIV filter but spring/hibernate is spawning too many transactions (one per select if they are not wrapped within a service class which is be the case in pathvariable resolvers for example).

While the system is still pretty fast I think this is not necessary and neither consistent with the rest of the architecture.

Let me explain:

Let's assume that I have a request mapping including two entities and the conversion is based on a `StringToEntityConverter`

The actual URL would be like this if we support GET: `http://localhost/app/link/User_231/Item_324`

```
@RequestMapping("/link/{user}/{item}", method="POST")
public String linkUserAndItem(@PathVariable("user") User user, @PathVariable("item") Item item) {
    userService.addItem(user, item);
    return "linked";
}


@Converter
// simplified
public Object convert(String classAndId) {
    return entityManager.find(getClass(classAndId), getId(classAndId));
}
```

The `UserService.addItem()` method is transactional so there is no issue here.

BUT:

The entity converter is resolving the User and the Item against the database before the call to the `Controller`, thus creating two selects, each running in it's own transaction. Then we have `@ModelAttribute` methods which might also issue some selects again and each will spawn a transaction.

And this is what I would like to change. I would like to create **ONE** readonly Transaction

I was not able to find any way to intercept/listen/etc... by the means of Spring.

First I wanted to override the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` but the resolver calls are well "hidden" inside the `invokeHandleMethod` method...

The `ModelFactory` is not a spring bean, so i cannot write an interceptor either.

So currently I only see a way by completely replacing the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`, but I would really like to avoid that.

And ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a design failure to me. OEMIV is usually a sign that you're doing it wrong™.

Instead, do:

```
@RequestMapping("/link/User_{userId}/Item_{itemId}", method="POST")
public String linkUserAndItem(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId,
                              @PathVariable("itemId") Long itemId) {
    userService.addItem(userId, itemId);
    return "linked";
}
```

Where your service layer takes care of fetching and manipulating the entities. This logic doesn't belong in the controller.

Comment: While i can see your point of OEMIV, i have to disagree. It's about a 50-50 chance of having people favouring or discouraging this practice ;) For me and my teams i've worked with a request is per se a unit of work. Either it fails or it works. But thata's not the point of the question. The OEMIV filter we just use to render the page. In case of errors this is still handled properly.

Comment: I'm firmly in the "views should be dumb" camp. Pass everything you actually need for a view in as a simple variable, preferably a string. Then your views are thin, your controllers are thin, and the service call is transactional and does the real work. You're clearly doing something non-standard given the lack of support in spring-core; perhaps you should reconsider this.

Comment: @MartinFrey I thought of a potential solution which doesn't involve changing everything: you *may* be able to use `spring-aop` to do a pointcut on your controller methods and manually start a transaction there or possibly annotate the AOP method with `@Transactional`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Up to this time i don't think we do anything wrong. A modelattribute method resolves an entity using a service and repository. It then passes the model to the requestmapping method which does it's part using a service. Just that each modelattribute method potentially uses a service call which needs a transaction. So i want to wrap the modelattributeresolver in total and not one by one. This is where spring does not support it and i could not yet find an AOP pointcut for example.

Comment: Try something like `@Transactional @Around("myapp.Controller.method()")`. [Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-around-advice)